# C++/C# Interoperability Type Conversion

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I am developing a program which uses dll driver file. I successfully linked the dll into my code but have a problem with one method

Dll function:

```
word NdEnumDevices(const char* const ** devs);
```

I've linked it to c# like this

```
[DllImport("NeurobitDrv.dll")]
    public static extern ushort NdEnumDevices(ref string[] devs);
```

As i don't have much experience with C++ I dont really understand what `const char* const ** devs` means. I know for sure that this argument receives an array of strings but i only get one element where should be 3

And it Throws out an Access violation Exception

Can someone tell me what type should i use in c#??

---

I've worked around it, just hardcoded string array with device names and it works just fine :D

Comment: I would imagine it should be a `string[,]`. Someone else can explain the `const`-ness or link to an article.

Comment: Nope. I've already tried it

Comment: `const char* const **` means a pointer to a pointer to a constant pointer to a constant char. `const char*` is used for c-strings. You're likely missing a level of indirection (i.e. the `**` part)

Comment: @OMGtechy That's what it literally means, but semantically it could mean either an array of C strings passed by pointer, or a 2D array of C strings, a nullable array of strings, an array of nullable strings... or it might not even be strings

Comment: @KABoissonneault yes, but we can't infer any more from the information given

Comment: Does something like (don't know for sure C# syntax) `ref string[][][] devs` make sense?

Comment: @CristiFati `string` should correspond to a `char*`, and each `[]` should correspond to a *.
Even if you ignore the `ref` keyword, that's too many indirections. C#'s `ref` probably only corresponds to C++/CLI's `%` references

Comment: `string` corresponds to `wchar_t*`, unless you specify the attribute `CharSet = Ansi` (see [DllImportAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx)).

Comment: Pretty hard to guess how you wrote your C++ code, it isn't clear why you force us to guess.  It *looks* like you are trying to return an array of strings.  But it is useless to the caller, it has no idea how many elements are in the array.  You might get away with that in C++ (not really) but certainly not in C#, a managed array knows its size.  No way that the pinvoke marshaller can possibly find out.  Always have the caller provide the storage for the array, you must add an extra argument that says how large it is.

Answer (score 0):

`const char* const ** devs` is likely the same as `const char* const *devs[]` which would be

```
pointer to 
  an array of
    constant pointers to
      constant characters.
```

This is most likely caused be the `ref` (although I'm not too sure about that). A `ref` to an array of strings could be compiled as a pointer to an array of strings.

As pointed out in [this](/q/10799685) question, you should be safe to use `const char*` for that.

I think what you could be missing is the length of the array. The function should be declared as

```
word NdEnumDevices(const char* devs[], unsigned int length);
// C#
[DllImport("NeurobitDrv.dll")]
private static extern ushort NdEnumDevices(string[] devs, UInt32 length);

public static ushort NdEnumDevices(string[] devs) {
    NdEnumDevices(devs, devs.Length); // Delegate for length
}
```

Comment: So my code should work just fine. Any ideas why it doesn't??

Comment: @CezaryKarabela It probably has to do with the fact that .NET's string and a char* are implemented radically different?
Either use a .NET string on the C++ side, or use C#'s unsafe code and use char* on the C# side

Comment: If it would be only a pointer to a null terminated string your code would work. The Marshaller constructs a System.String from the first char* pointer found. But there is no default Marshalling for char**. Therefore you can try to marshall it as "ref IntPtr" And then read thethe strings with Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi

But for that you have to know how many strings are there in  the array.. are they terminated with two 0 values?